# Blazemeter: Does Jmeter engine in Blazemeter read data from csv file in sequentially order or in random order?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, blazemeter

I have analysed that Jmeter is reading data from csv file in sequential order only(from row 1 to end of line) but I wonder how Blazemeter will read values from csv file! Whether sequential or random order?

I am experiencing multiple login detected during login activity request performed via Blazemeter.

Can any one help me on this?

Answer (score 2):

In general BlazeMeter reads CSV files just exactly standalone JMeter does.

If you use > 1 JMeter engines it might be the case when 2 engines sending the same username/password combination. If this is something you would like to avoid you could use `${__P(InstanceID)}` property as CSV file prefix or postfix so different JMeter engines could use different CSV files.

See [How To Setup A Different CSV File For Each JMeter Engine?](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733699-How-to-setup-a-different-CSV-file-for-each-JMeter-engine-) article for more details.

Comment: Hi Dmitri, Thanks. I use only one engine in Blazemeter and I am sure all the records are unique in my csv file but still I see multiple login errors.

Comment: I would suggest either sharing your test plan or contacting BlazeMeter support as the options could be numerous. The most obvious is: if you have multiple iterations and don't clear cookies in-between there might be sessions clash. If you're using [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-http-cookie-manager-jmeter-not-cookie-jar) - make sure you're clearing cookies each Thread Group loop.